# How to index a tensor and change the value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a algorithm with `tensorflow`.
Following is the `NumPy` version of the wanted code:

```py
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
sets = {1,5,7}
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range(10):
    if i in sets:
        y[i] = x[i]
```

which gets the result:

```
y = [0,2,0,0,0,6,0,8,0,0]
```

How to implement this in `tensorflow`?
Is there any way to to implement this in `tensorflow` using the same logic, not by converting `NumPy` arrays to tensor after the calculation, but instead doing all the operation using tensor (e.g. using tensor to index the tensor, and assign its value by x(tensor) if the index is in the set).

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Your code seems to work fine.

Comment: @Hoppo his code is fine. He is asking how to do the same thing in tensorflow...

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in TensorFlow like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
sets = tf.constant([1, 5, 7])
y = tf.constant([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
y2 = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(y, tf.expand_dims(sets, 1), tf.gather(x, sets))
print(y2.numpy())
# [0 2 0 0 0 6 0 8 0 0]
```

If your `y` is always made of zeros (that is, you only want to "fill" the positions given by `sets`), then you can just do:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
sets = tf.constant([1, 5, 7])
y2 = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(sets, 1), tf.gather(x, sets), tf.shape(x))
print(y2.numpy())
# [0 2 0 0 0 6 0 8 0 0]
```

As an alternative method, you can do it with masking too, although I don't think it should be faster:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
sets = tf.constant([1, 5, 7])
y = tf.constant([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
s = tf.shape(x, out_type=sets.dtype)
mask = tf.math.reduce_any(tf.equal(tf.range(s[0]), tf.expand_dims(sets, 1)), 0)
y2 = tf.where(mask, x, y)
# Or if y is always zeros:
#y2 = x * tf.dtypes.cast(mask, x.dtype)
print(y2.numpy())
# [0 2 0 0 0 6 0 8 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understood your question. But here's what i think you need. You can convert numpy array to tensor using

```
test_array = np.array([1,2,3,4])
random1_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_array)
```

Here's an alternative way if you don't want to use numpy and convert it to tensor.

```
test_array = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4])
test_array_2 = tf.Variable([5,6,7,8])
```

now you can do all sort of calculations like add, substract, etc.
like you do with numpy arrays.

Comment: I know there is a way to using convert_to_tensor , is there any way to calculate in tensor way instead of convert after calculate by numpy ? Thanks